I couldn't compile the codes, shows error of usetkzobj
Question: Getting errors while compiling the below codes. The error is about usetkzobj{all}. I am not able to solve this error.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](B,C)
    \tkzDefPoint(1.5,1.5){A}
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,A)
    \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](B,A)
    \tkzDrawSegment(C,A)
    \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](C,A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.3 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!10](C,B,A)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.3 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!10](A,C,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.3 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!10](B,A,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=-0.7mm](C,B,A){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=-0.7mm](A,C,B){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=2mm](B,A,C){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](B,C){$2$\,cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Usetkzobj is not necessary with the new version !

If you use pgfplots (which is not needed in your example), you should consider setting \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} or similar.

With 2024/04/19 5.10c tkz-euclide.sty, your code compiles if you remove
\usetkzobj{all}. If you search the usetkzobj forum, you'll find more questions and answers.
I've simplified your code a little.
The triangle is not equilateral, but that's probably on purpose ...
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](B,C) \tkzGetPoint{A}creates an equilateral triangle.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(1.5,1.5){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
    \tkzMarkSegments[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](B,A B,C C,A)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,A B,A B,C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](B,C)
    \tkzMarkAngles[size=0.3 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!10](C,B,A A,C,B B,A,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=-0.7mm](C,B,A){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=-0.7mm](A,C,B){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8,yshift=2mm](B,A,C){$60^{\circ}$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](B,C){$2$\,cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



With 2024/04/19 5.10c tkz-euclide.sty Can you tell me more about it.

For several versions, it is no longer necessary to use usetkzobj. There have been a few changes since the first versions, the most important change being the separation of the definition of points and plots. This can be done with the lua option and a lualatex compilation, but it is best to use the new tkz-elements package, which is created entirely from Lua. Version 5 of tkz-euclide is the last one, only the bugs will be fixed.

You mean to say I have to update my tkz packages.

@SandyM What is your version of tkz-euclide?

It's updated. Thank you so much.
